# Why does a category have both parent_id and path?

Tags: category, database

I was wondering...

As of 1.9.1.0, `catalog_category_entity` still has both a `path` as well as a `parent_id` field. Why is that? Isn't that just redundant information? You could follow the `parent_id` up the tree to resolve the `path`; is it made for query speed purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's somehow redundant, but it's an easier way to find parent nodes (full path up to root) or child nodes (all levels) for some categories with one single select.

```
Select * from catalog_category_entity where path LIKE `1/2/40/`
```

will give you all child nodes of id 40.

and `explode('/', $category->getPath())` will give you all ancestors of the category.

Conclusion, redundant data for performance reasons.

Comment: Worth stating the obvious, having the path means you don't of course need to load the parent category to determine it's parent and so on up the chain.